# Don't understand a symbol in this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, schematics, electromagnetic

[image: circuit]

I'm trying to fully understand this circuit. I don't understand how the connection from the power source is going into the center of this coil. What does this represent?

The circuit is for an electromagnetic pendulum driver. Depending on which side the pendulum, with a magnet, comes across the coil, it triggers either Q1 or Q2 and gives the pendulum a push.

Comment: Where does this circuit come from? I would like to swap base and collector to make it work.

Comment: 3nigma_ - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that if a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be named & linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). Therefore please [edit] your question to include the original source link for that image (and please remember it's your responsibility to do that in future). Thanks. (Please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules.)

Answer (score 4):

> *I don't understand how the connection from the power source is going
> into the center of this coil. What does this represent?*

The centre of the coil has what we call a tap or tapping point. Basically you can think of it as two magnetically coupled coils (left and right) that are "joined" electrically. That "join" is what you see.

Answer (score 0):

It's an inconsistent schematic. There are dots everywhere else that wires join. There should be a dot between the centre of the coil and the wire that goes to the battery positive.

Comment: I agree the schematic is inconsistent (as in: why does the inductor not get a component designator? What about the battery?), but I'd consider it *one* component (because there *is* an internal flow of energy that is *not* represented by the electrical connection between the "half-coils", if you will), and has three connections.

Comment: I don't think the two halves of the coil need to be magnetically coupled for this circuit to work.  You can think of this as having two separate coils.

Comment: @SteveSh uh, wait, I need to work that into my mental model of the circuit. (though what I said about *coupled* inductor halves, whether they're used for their coupling or not, would stand)

Comment: @Marcus Muller - Me too.  This drives a pendulum back and forth, which is a really slow oscillation compared to how fast the electronics and the magnetic coupling between the coils (or coil halves) operate.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it looks to me.

When the pendulum comes from the right, it creates a small current in the coil which flows into the base of one transistor Q2.  The collector of that transistor then drags down the opposite end of the coil. The resistor R2 stops this end of the coil being dragged down. Because of the capacitor C2, this is a pulse/spike.  The magnetic field created in the coil kicks the pendulum away from the centre.

Then the pendulum comes from the other side and the opposite cycle fires.  You can think of the coil as two coils.  Its probably built this way for convenience.

There is a vaguely similar circuit for a spinning top on a pedestal, that seemingly never stops.

Comment: It doesn't do any of that if the two BJT's burn out from having the supply voltage applied directly to their b-e junctions.